# Proving the points $P,O,N$ are collinear

Tags: geometry, contest-math

In a triangle $ABC$, let $M$ be the midpoint of side $BC$ and $N$ be the midpoint of median $AM$. Let $O$ be the circumcentre of triangle $ABM$. If the circumcircle of triangle $BOM$ cuts the side $AB$ at $P$(leaving the point B), prove that the points $P,O,N$ are collinear.

I am quite weak at geometry, so please tell me how to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is the following.

Let $ON \cap AB = P'$. It suffices to show that $P'$ lie on the circumcircle of $BOM$.

After that, we will have $P'=P$, and then we will have $P$ lie on $ON$.

Let $\angle BAM = a$. We begin angle chasing.

We have $$\angle BP'O + \angle BMO = (a+ \angle ANO) + (\angle BMA - \angle OMA) = a+90+(180- \angle B - a) -(90 - \angle B) = 180$$

Details - $$\angle BP'O + \angle AP'O = 180 = \angle AP'O + \angle BAM + \angle ANO$$

From $NO$ being the perpendicular bisector of $AM$, $\angle ANO=90$.

From $O$ being the circumcenter of $ABM$, $\angle OMA = 90- \angle B$.

Therefore, we have $B, M, O, P'$ cyclic, as desired.

Comment: Oops, I will edit the soution.

Comment: Just one doubt. How is angle $OMA$ equal to what you wrote. I am just not getting it.

Comment: $\angle MOA = 2 \angle B$, and $\angle OMA = \frac{180-\angle MOA}{2} = 90-\angle B$.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!!

Comment: Wait I found a ridiculously easy solution. Since $B, P, O,M$ is given to be cyclic, we have $\angle POM = 180-\angle B$, and since $O$ is the circumcenter of $ABM$, we have $\angle NOM = \frac{1}{2} \angle AOM = \angle B$, so $\angle POM + \angle NOM = 180$, so $P,O,N$ are colinear as desired. (What was I even doing...)

Comment: Oh my god. Now this is brilliant. Man, you are a genius.